# Unable to install winehq-staging, Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: 16.04, wine

I have been running wine on Ubuntu 16.04, installed via `sudo apt-get install wine`, but I would like to switch to wine-staging.  I am attempting to follow the instructions at https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

I first uninstalled wine and made sure all packages were up to date:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine wine-mono wine-gecko winetricks
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then rebooted and ran the following series of commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
```

However, the command to install `winehq-staging` fails with unmet dependency on wine-staging:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 2.13.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing wine-staging fails with unmet dependency on `wine-staging-i386`:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging : Depends: wine-staging-i386 (= 2.13.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing `wine-staging-i386` fails with various unmet dependencies on `-i386` packages.  Showing a few of them (the list is much longer):

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging-i386

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.9) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.9) but it is not installable
```

*(snip)*

```
                          Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install the first one, it is not available:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386

Package libasound2:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libasound2-data

E: Package 'libasound2:i386' has no installation candidate
```

However, package `libasound2-data` is already installed and the latest version.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by checking all checkboxes in "Software and Updates".  After that, I was able to successfully install all dependencies and wine staging via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: Enabling `universe` package in the "Ubuntu Software" tap of the "Software & Updates" tool did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

this is an addition to the answer of [Elber CM](https://askubuntu.com/a/985613/772891)

before execution of "$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging" I needed to install the following libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
$ sudo apt-get install wine-staging-i386
$ sudo apt-get install wine-staging
```

and finally

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

voila, now it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a great advice - I tried to solve it for hours, pulling my hairs off, until I found your answer. It is interesting, why the `aptitude` did not see this solution - the only advice it gave me included uninstalling 90% of all packages on my system.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to install wine for Ubuntu 18.04 with next steps:

```
# basic steps
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'

# fix of the broken dependency
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport

# install winehq
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Found the solution [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/nstall-wine-4-8-ubuntu-19-04-18-04/).

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  That one backport PPA was the only thing I needed to make the official instructions work.

Answer (score 2):

*English is not my native language so please be patient.*

Apparently the solution is a little more complex, following tutorial on:

https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/wine-1-9-11-on-ubuntu-16-04/

It's necesary to install first some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libasound2-dev:i386 libgsm1-dev:i386 libjpeg8-dev:i386 liblcms2-dev:i386 libldap2-dev:i386 libmpg123-dev:i386 libopenal-dev:i386 libv4l-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxinerama-dev:i386 libxml2-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
```

Then make a update again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Again some missing libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libcapi20-dev:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libsane:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 libgd3:i386
```

Finally make the installation required:

**Stable branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

**Development branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

**Staging branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

PSDT: Some of the librares could be included, that depends of other programs that could use them and Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to also concur that

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

fixed my broken dependency issue.

might have installed those libraries previously mentioned for nothing.