# Problem installing winehq-staging | Dependencies | Ubuntu 16.04LTS | 64 bits

Tags: command-line, package-management, wine

I have a problem installing winehq-staging, which I'll be using to play some little games.

- When I run `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging` it tells me I need "wine-staging". When I try to install "wine-staging" it tells me to install something else, and this continues infinitely.
- When I try `aptitude` it lists all the packages I need but tells me none of them will be installed.

I have already done the following:

- Updated, upgraded and dist-upgraded my packages.
- Manually purged all wine packages and configurations.
- Activated multiarch with i386.

The output of sudo apt-get install wine-staging is the following:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install wine-staging
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging : Depends: wine-staging-i386 (= 2.18.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt-get update` output:

```
pop@201600000:~$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release
Ign:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-fr
Ign:8 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-fr
Ign:15 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-fr
Ign:8 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-fr
Ign:15 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-fr
Ign:8 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-fr
Ign:15 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-fr
Ign:8 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-fr
Ign:15 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main Translation-fr
Ign:8 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted Translation-fr
Ign:15 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial/main i386 Packages
Hit:17 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Hit:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Get:19 http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease [3344 B]                  
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:21 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease             
Get:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release [2136 B]      
Ign:23 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing InRelease
Hit:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease         
Ign:19 http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease                           
Ign:26 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian stable InRelease
Hit:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease        
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kranich/cinnamon/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Ign:29 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing Release
Hit:30 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian stable Release 
Hit:32 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:33 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Ign:35 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main i386 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:41 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:41 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:41 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:41 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
Hit:42 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:36 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main all Packages
Ign:37 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main Translation-fr
Ign:39 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 5480 B in 18s (295 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
W: The repository 'http://qgis.org/debian xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/debian testing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please post output of `sudo apt-get install wine-staging`.

Comment: do you have muulti arch enabled? `sudo dpkg --add-architecure i386`

Comment: Have you followed the official installation instructions? Click this [link](https://wine-staging.com/installation.html) and scroll down to the Ubuntu section.

Comment: @Liso Done! ravery Also done! marko That's what I've done so far!

Comment: @Didan974 Please run: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install wine-staging`. So the output would be in English language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984844/e-unable-to-locate-package-winehq-stable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

*English is not my native language so please be patient.*

Apparently the solution is a little more complex, already published an answer in:

https://askubuntu.com/a/985613/497512

It's necesary to install first some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libasound2-dev:i386 libgsm1-dev:i386 libjpeg8-dev:i386 liblcms2-dev:i386 libldap2-dev:i386 libmpg123-dev:i386 libopenal-dev:i386 libv4l-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxinerama-dev:i386 libxml2-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
```

Then make a update again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Again some missing libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libcapi20-dev:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libsane:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 libgd3:i386
```

Finally make the installation required:

**Stable branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

**Development branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

**Staging branch**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

PSDT: Some of the librares could be included, that depends of other programs that could use them and Ubuntu version.