# E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable

Tags: software-installation, wine, 17.10

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: The package is `wine-stable`, afaict.

Answer (score 35):

The name of the install package is different from that stated in the wiki.
Instead of typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

you type:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable
```

That will install the proper package. I just installed Wine and that's how this works.

Comment: Still true as of this date.

Comment: God bless you and bless the womb that bore you.

Comment: bruh its 2023 and they haven't fixed it yet!

Answer (score 23):

The winehq-stable package is not in the default Ubuntu repositories, so apt is unable to locate it. In Ubuntu 17.10 install wine-stable instead. The wine-stable version is 2.0 in Ubuntu 17.10. The wine-stable version is 3.0 in Ubuntu 18.04-23.10.

To install winehq-stable open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install -y wine-stable
```

Other suggested packages to install along with wine-stable are: *dosbox playonlinux winbind wine-binfmt winetricks*

Comment: If you're coming here because of this problem with Ubuntu 22.04, this answer works well on 22.04.

Answer (score 13):

You don't have the necessary setup work completed to add that package. According to [the WineHQ Wiki's Ubuntu page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. If your computer is 64-bit, add the 32-bit architecture:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
3. Add the repository:

   ```
   wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
   sudo apt-key add Release.key
   sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
   ```
4. Update repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install `winehq-stable`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
   ```
6. If `apt-get` mentions missing dependencies, install them and retry the install of `winehq-stable`.

Comment: Worked after using `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 76F1A20FF987672F` because adding `Release.key` alone was not enough apparently.

Comment: if anyone is using Debian Bookworm (Debian 12), try to run this too before running the `apt-get update`:  `sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/dists/bookworm/winehq-bookworm.sources`

Answer (score 3):

Add 32 bit architecture and WINE's key

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

To add WINE repository on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

To add WINE repository on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

To add WINE repository on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
```

Update APT cache and install WINE:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I've finally found the solution.

1. Run command to enable 32 bit architecture:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
2. Download and install the repository key via this command:

   ```
   wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
   sudo apt-key add winehq.key
   ```
3. Add wine repository via command (for Ubuntu 19.10):

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
   ```

   **NOTE:** You may replace "eoan" in the code with:

   ```
   bionic for Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint 19.x
   xenial for Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18.x
   ```
4. Add PPA for the required `libfaudio0` library:

   For Ubuntu 18.04, Linux Mint 19.x, and Ubuntu 19.04 only, as higher Ubuntu releases already have libfaudio0 in the main repositories.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
   ```
5. Finally install Wine 5.0 stable via command:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
   ```

   (Optional) After successfully installed Wine 5.0, you may remove the PPAs by launching Software & Updates utility and navigating to Other Software tab.

Thanks to [this guy](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-wine-5-0-stable-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/)!

Comment: This worked on my ubuntu 18.04 system. The `libfaudio0` bit had been tripping me up.