# How can I fix this Wine/Terminal error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, wine

Hi I just updated  to Ubuntu 22.04 and I was trying to install wine but I keep on facing the error :E Unable to locate Winehq-stable. If I try the development branch it works but when I try to install Grapejuice I have the same error. It this a bug or is something?
Someone please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984844/e-unable-to-locate-package-winehq-stable)

Comment: It's a bug only in the sense that the upstream instructions you are likely following are incomplete or unclear, so this is a common question for folks following those instructions. If you install Wine from the Ubuntu repositories instead of upstream, you don't get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to install Wine, you need to do this: 
`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable`

as described here: [E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984844/e-unable-to-locate-package-winehq-stable)