# How do I install "wine-staging" on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine, games, playonlinux

Ok, so I'm about to install some games on my computer.

PlayOnLinux asks me for "wine-staging", which seems not to be a package...

How the hell can I get it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install winehq-staging, Ubuntu 16.04 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943434/unable-to-install-winehq-staging-ubuntu-16-04-64bit)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should see https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine-Staging
and the https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-wine-staging-ubuntu/
It's available https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu also. It shows the way to install the staging package. You can go to #ubuntu in freenode also for futher help

TL;DR

```bsh
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main' # 19.04, see other version
```

Comment: No, winehq-staging says me "unmet dependencies : wine-staging" :c

Comment: Try to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/943434/unable-to-install-winehq-staging-ubuntu-16-04-64bit. It should help you on the answered section

Answer (score 0):

Okay so wine-staging is simply not available for 18.04 (bionic), i had to add xenial PPA for it, then run a normal `sudo apt-get install winehq-staging` which provide the wine-staging packet.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me installing seamlessly 'wine-staging' on Ubuntu 18.04 (and explain how to do it for Ubuntu 19.10, 19.04, 18.04 or 16.04, Linux Mint 19.* and 18.*, and Debian 10):

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/how-to-install-wine-staging-development.html