# Not able to install wine on 16.04 dependencies error

Tags: 16.04, wine

Im new to linux (ubuntu 16.04 lts) and I have been trying to install wine for Sketchup pro 8

I did the follwoing step to install the wine

```
1. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  #to enable 32 bit
2.wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 
  #to get the key
3. sudo apt-key add winehq.key #to add the key
4.sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
5. sudo apt update
6.sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

After the step 6 I got the error umet dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0.3~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install it with aptitude to resolve the dependencies

```
7.sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
```

But then I got the error

```
      Keep the following packages at their current version:                                               
1)      gcc-5-base:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
2)      libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]                                                           
3)      libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                    
4)      libboost-system1.58.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
5)      libcapnp-0.5.3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
6)      libegl1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
7)      libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
8)      libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                       
9)      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
10)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
11)     libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
12)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
13)     libicu55:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                     
14)     libjack-jackd2-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
15)     libllvm6.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
16)     libmirclient9:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
17)     libmircommon7:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
18)     libmircore1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                  
19)     libmirprotobuf3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
20)     libosmesa6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
21)     libprotobuf-lite9v5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                          
22)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                      
23)     libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
24)     libstdc++6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
25)     libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
26)     libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                                         
27)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                      
28)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
29)     wine-stable [Not Installed]                                                                       
30)     wine-stable-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
31)     winehq-stable [Not Installed]                                                                     

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                                        
32)     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 recommends libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 | libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386
33)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libfontconfig1:i386                                              
34)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libglu1-mesa:i386 | libglu1:i386                                 
35)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libosmesa6:i386                                                  
36)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386 | libsane1:i386                                     
37)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libsdl2-2.0-0:i386                                               
38)     wine-stable-i386:i386 recommends libxslt1.1:i386                                                  


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I had try to just simply install wine by removing the winehq repository but still getting the dependency issue. I even try to manually install the dependency from
[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943434/unable-to-install-winehq-staging-ubuntu-16-04-64bit)

But still im getting more error to resolve the dependency issue

Comment: I tried the command to get list of broken packages but I get nothing.

Comment: I recreated new resouces list but still same issue

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy wine-stable winehq-stable` along with `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` to the question.

Comment: Did you able to resolve the issue?
I have the same problem, and can't resolve it yet

Answer (score 0):

This may be a 16.04 specific issue. I've had issues installing various programs on 16.04 due to unmet dependencies before. If you can, install Ubuntu 18.04 and try again, as adding 18.04 packages to a 16.04 system will make a broken Ubuntu system. I ran a simulated install on my 18.04 VM and everything seems to have worked, not quite sure about 16.04 as I don't have a system image to work with right now and downloading one will take all day.

Comment: Re. your post in Chat about KDE neon … Unfortunately, it is [not supported here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). KDE neon is supported at our related site [unix.se], [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).